# Getting VBA to loop through an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database with a set of numbers from 1~100. I would like VBA to run through this list in column A and, on areas where A is between 20 and 40, type McFly on column B.

The code I have gives me a mismatch error 13 on the line that starts with "If list >="

```
Dim list As Range
Dim list_readthru As Range
Set list = Range("A2", Range("A50").End(xlUp))
For Each list_readthru In list
If list >= 20 And list <=40 Then Range("B:B") = "McFly"
Next list_readthru
End Sub
```

I am having problems identifying what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you want `list.value` but `range("B:B")` needs more work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array, you can have an array:

```
Sub MM()

Dim list, i

list = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A2", [A50].End(xlUp)))

For i = 1 To UBound(list)
   If list(i) >= 20 And list(i) <= 40 Then Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "McFly"
Next

End Sub
```

---

However I don't see how this is any different from just putting a formula in column B:

```
With Range("B2", [A50].End(xlUp))
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-1]>=20,RC[-1]<=40),""McFly"","""""")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You dim `list` as a Range object (not an array), so work with it as a range. Eg, `list.value` Same goes for `list_readthru`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few things mixed up here. Try this:

```
Dim list As Range
Dim list_readthru As Range
Set list = Range("A2", Range("A50").End(xlUp))
For Each list_readthru In list
    If list_readthru >= 20 And list_readthru <=40 Then 
        Cells(list_readthru.row, 2) = "McFly"
    End If
Next list_readthru
End Sub
```